# PLSQL and Connect by Prior options in Google big query

Tags: google-bigquery

While moving our Oracle warehouse to Big query, one constraint we have come across is what to do about procedural(PLSQL) code that we have in Oracle and how to implement it in Big Query.

Also we derive Hierarchy using Connect By Prior. Is there something similar in Big Query?

Regards,
Sreekanth

Comment: BigQuery has no such features.  Are you sure BigQuery is the correct tool for the job/migration?

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean for migration. I ment while rebuilding the warehouse in cloud we wanted to see what options do we have to implement oracle plsql and connect by prior (for hierarchy generation) kind of code in Big Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update August 2020**

As per [Release notes](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#March_30_2020) "*Scripting and stored procedures are now Generally Available.*" This was announced on March 30, 2020.
You may find what you are interested in the following documentation sections [scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) and [stored procedures](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_procedure).
Although, `CONNECT BY PRIOR` seems to be still unsupported.

Answer (score 3):

Procedural SQL: BigQuery currently does not provide a procedural/scripting language, so the best option is to recreate this type of logic using a client library, such as Python or Java, where you can express conditions, loops, exception handling, and so on. Alternatively, you can use a tool such as [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) for workflow orchestration.

`CONNECT BY PRIOR`: The best option is to express parent/child operations using `JOIN`s, as BigQuery does not have the concept of primary/foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you ought to keep away building logic within the target database. Because this may be OK as a tactical move but will inevitably lock you down to another vendor (Google BQ). The logic is that why bother migrating from Oracle to another if you want to hold on to the old practices? If you want to emulate Oracle in Cloud you might as well consider migrating to Oracle Cloud Autonomous Data Warehouse (ADW) which should run the code without change. As others stated, the Oracle procedure logic can be done with Python say PyCharm in Spark that will work independently of the underlying target database.